# How to dynamic add/edit/remove controller with actions in web app asp.net mvc without using my assemblies on IIS? It's possible? Php can do it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, content-management-system

I am developing CMS-like web application in **VS 2015** on language **C#** with **ASP.NET MVC 4.5**.

This product was used only for my company's own. The product know as **SVGMnemo**.
Initially **SVGMnemo** was used with other functions. This product was aimed at display output technical mnemonic schemes for real-time signals from PLC in intranet. The schemes must be in **svg** format, then it's integrate in **html5**.

Designer draws technical schema with use a specific set of rules in his favorite graphic editor, for example: **Adobe Illustrator** or **MS Visio** and then export it into **SVG**.
Next step is to copy this picture in specific folder in **SVGMnemo**. Then **SVGMnemo** automatically linkes on tags, that set on this picture.

It looks like **Wonderware system** but **SVGMnemo** didn't have tags manual control for a long time.

Actually, our clients are technical specialists at manufacture and often they want to add new functional, new schemes and etc.
Of course, we did't like it, because we had a fixed picture where *a programmer with Visual Studio was required for any changes*.
And also, our clients security departments usually restrict deploy and install the external products such as Visual Studio on the production server.
Administrators of security departments often **close all ports for protocols such as tcp/ip, ftp**, etc.
We can install our product on the server and setup it only once with use *rdp*.
Later we will not have access to the server for change our code. 
But we have access to our sites through VPN with use **http/https** and only couple open ports, for example 80 and 443.

So It was decided to add javascript-editor **CodeMirror** in *SVGMnemo*.
But now during the installation our web application on IIS we should provide access to all project files if we want edit their later.
And also `web.config` has configuration:

```
 <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>.
```

Thus, we have full control for edit `js, css, svg, html, etc.` front-end elements.
And I can edit user's views `.cshtml` files by adding new items menu for new techical schemes.
I know that it violates safety precautions, but no one has access to modify files if user hasn't rights on the *CMS area*.

But without *Visual Studio* I can't add or edit `.cs` files, that contains controllers with new actions and new specific routes. 
Because after deploy we have folder **bin** with `.dll`(assemblies)!

In long time ago I used ASP.NET 2.0 and 3.5.
**Web sites** deployed on IIS always had **source files**, that I could changed later,  but this required server pool restart. 
In VS 2015 for web application ASP.NET MVC it's impossible to publish files as source.
We must manualy copyied project files on IIS and after server pool has been started, IIS recompile sources **once**. 
This is very bad solution for me.

**How i can add/edit/delete mvc controller with actions without VS?** Without compiled assemblies.
I think it would be great if controllers were **declared in templates** `.cshtml`!

Example of what I need: https://dotnetfiddle.net/
Select Project Type as MVC.
Delete Model and View, in the Controller paste the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Index()
        {
            return "Yep, it's magic work!";
        }

    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is any kind of CMS on ASP.NET MVC where possible to edit controller's class on a running web application without VS?

I will appreciate any idea!

Answer (score 0):

> How i can add/edit/delete a mvc controller with actions without VS? And without compiled assemblies.

As far as I know, it's impossible to edit add/edit/delete a mvc controller with actions without compiling the application.

ASP.NET is web application framework , PHP is server-side scripting language. They are different.

We need to compile the whole application, then it will generate the right dll which used to handle the request and return the right response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is sad, but I would not want to just give up and rewrite everything in php.
I edited my question, with an example where these actions are possible.